# How to assign this click handler to stop bubbling

Tags: jquery

Considering the following,

```js
$('.child').click(function(event) {
  console.log('click');
  // stuff...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="child btn">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="child btn">
    <p>goodbye</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The event is firing twice. To stop multiple events firing, after reading up on some other posts I added

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Does this mean I need these 2 lines every time I add a click handler to a class element that might have more than 1 instance?

Comment: Given your HTML sample that event should not be firing twice. You have no nested elements for it to bubble up through.

Comment: Please note in your jquery you are missing a `)` after `}`

Comment: You can see from the executable snippet I edited in to your question that the events only fire once. We may need to see a more complete sample of your HTML and JS if you still have this issue. Note that I also added the missing `)` in the JS code, as that must have just been a typo in the question other wise the click handler wouldn't have worked at all.

Comment: I think it's too complicated to post my full code, but good to know the code above as is should work. I will compare and see what is different

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, but I was doing something totally boneheaded. I had the event handler in a partial view, which was being called twice, so there were 2 instances of the handler. DOH!!!!  Lesson learned about having script in partials.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a syntax error. Here's is the right syntax to solve the error.

```
$('.child').click(function (event) {
  console.log("stuff");
})
```

Comment: If that syntax error was actually in the OPs code then the event handler wouldn't have been bound at all, let alone execute multiple times. It's obviously just a typo in the question

Comment: of course, he said that the function fired twice, i dont know how he do that because it has a sintax error... with this code the function execute only when needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.child:first').click(function (event) {
        //stuff
        alert("hello clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not at all. Your code is ok. stopPropagation is helpfull when we have event bound on both child and parent. so while clicking on child the parent event will also fire. To prevent this you can add stopPropagation.

```
$('.parent').click(function(event) {
console.log('click');

});

$('.child').click(function(event) {
console.log('click');
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop the event propagating outside clicked child element.